# How to write a function declaration that can handle multiple parameters in C?

Tags: c

How to write a function declaration that can handle multiple parameters like `printf()`

In other words, I can call the function in several ways

- Func (Var, 12, False);
- or Func (Var, 12, 14, False);
- or Func (Var1, Var2, 12, 14, False);
- or etc.

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: It's called "varargs". You can google it for plenty of examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commented, it is called varargs ([variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) arguments), see [va_arg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/va_arg.3.html) man page.

However, be aware that your function should know, at least at *run time* how many arguments its has and the type of each argument. This is not evident from your examples.

Given your examples:

```
Func (Var, 12, False);
Func (Var, 12, 14, False);
Func (Var1, Var2, 12, 14, False);
```

I cannot even guess what is distinguishing the above calls. Let's imagine that we have declared

```
int Var; // Var is an integer
double Var1; // Var1 is a double-precision floating point
char* Var2;  // Var2 "is" a string
```

Then, from the point of view of the implementor of `Func`, I cannot see what differentiate your different calls. Perhaps you should accept to give to `Func` an additional *first* constant string argument (like e.g. [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) does) describing the number and types of the other arguments, so change your example to:

```
Func("iib", Var, 12, false);
Func("iiib", Var, 12, 14, false);
Func("dsiib", Var1, Var2, 12, 14, False);
```

with the *convention* (that you should *document*) that the first argument to `Func` is a constant string describing the types of other arguments. `i`for `int` argument, `b` for `bool` argument, `d` for `double`, `s` for `char*` (strings), etc. You would have declared:

```
void Func(const char*, ...);
```

Another possible *convention* would be to prefix each argument by some enumerated value:

```
enum kindarg_en { EndArg, BoolArg, IntArg, DoubleArg, StringArg };
```

Then your calls become

```
Func (IntArg, Var,   IntArg, 12,   BoolArg, false,   EndArg);
Func (IntArg, Var,  IntArg, 12,  IntArg, 14,  BoolArg, false,  EndArg);
Func (DoubleArg, Var1,  StringArg, Var2,   IntArg, 12,   IntArg, 14, 
      BoolArg, false,   EndArg);
```

The above is of course for the C language. For C++ (notably with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)), you can design all of it differently (using [function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), or [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), etc...).

In C, you should be sure that the number and type of arguments can be determined at runtime (and the first argument should have some fixed type).
You should have some *documented convention* about the actual number and types of arguments. It could even be much more ugly (e.g. setting a global variable describing the signature of the following call).

Notice that variadic functions tend to become out of fashion. In the 1980s or 1990s (and even today on 32 bits [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_convention), but not on [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)) arguments were passed on the stack, and the facilities from `<stdarg.h>` where simply implemented (by incrementing the stack pointer e.g. in a non-portable assembly code). On current [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)-s, notably [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (for 64 bits x86 processors on Linux) things are much more complex, and variadic functions (i.e. `va_start`....) need deep compiler support; on GCC you have [varargs builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Varargs.html) for that purpose (so `stdarg.h` is provided by the compiler).

At last notice that GCC provides some specific extensions to help to type-check variadic function calls. At the very least, consider using some [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (e.g. `format` if you declare a `printf`-like function, or `sentinel` if the last argument should be zero or null...). If you are more ambitious (e.g. if you are developing your library  for others, with some important variadic functions), you could *customize GCC* with your own attributes, by extending GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) -a domain specific language to extend GCC- or more painfully with your GCC plugin manually coded in C++ ... For MELT, the (unfinished) `ex06` example from [melt-examples](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-examples) illustrates how to type some [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) calls: so the compiler is *sometimes* able to issue some warnings when a call to the variadic `json_pack` is ill-formed.

Comment: That is a good explanation. +1 from me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [varargs](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/cyclone/online-manual/main-screen010.html) function.

> C functions that take a variable number of arguments (vararg
>   functions) are syntactically convenient for the caller, but C makes it
>   very difficult to ensure safety. The callee has no fool-proof way to
>   determine the number of arguments or even their types. Also, there is
>   no type information for the compiler to use at call-sites to reject
>   bad calls.

You can find on how to use the varargs here: [Writing a ``varargs'' Function](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html)

Comment: That should be a comment unless you plan on expanding.

Comment: @Purrfection:- Yes I did that but by that time I received a downvote! :(